# Regular expression for setting unicode for numbers and words

Tags: java, regex

I have this sentence:
"I have 20 bananas at 11:00 o'clock, and I want 21-00".

I need to set a unicode for it. 
"\u200e" the wrap for numbers, and "\u200f" is the wrap for words.

The result should be:

"\u200fI have \u200f\u200e20\u200e\u200f bananas at \u200f\u200e11:00\u200e\u200f o'clock, and I want \u200f\u200e21-00\u200e"

How can I do that on a string in java ?

**UPDATE**

My sentence is an hebrew sentence.
"היום יום שלישי 20:00 בערב"

The expected result:
"\u200fהיום יום שלישי \u200f\u200e20:00\u200e\u200fבערב\u200f"

Comment: What About words in non-English characters? Do French words get wrapped? Do Chinese words get wrapped? Are - and : and . The only non-digits that are considered part of a number and/or part of a word

Comment: Actually I need this for hebrew words

Comment: Well in that case the question is very poorly specified, and it will be hard to get a correct answer. Perhaps edit it to give some more concrete examples. One example is always a poor number. 3 or 4 well thought out examples makes for a better question. Kudos for listing expected output though

Comment: Shouldn't `11:00` become split, or would the entire time be considered a number?

Comment: It can be splitted, but I think it's the same as not splitting it.
Maybe the regex will be more simple if it will be splitted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do multiple replaces.

```
String s = "I have 20 bananas at 11:00 o'clock, and I want 21-00";
s = s.replaceAll("([ ',\\p{Alpha}]+)", "<$1>");
s = s.replaceAll("([-:\\d]+)", "{$1}");
System.out.println(s);
```

prints

```
<I have >{20}< bananas at >{11:00}< o'clock, and I want >{21-00}
```

I used different symbols for easy readability, but you can use the unicode characters. The `\\p{Alpha}` should accept letters in all character sets.

Comment: Was in the middle of answering when I noticed how much more awesome your answer is than mine was going to be. You win this round. +1

Comment: @Keppil if there are any numbers in the first replace (which would be words), there is a problem. ;)

Comment: The character http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200e/index.htm is not a digit..